# check delivery is avialble or not using "PIN/ZIP" checker in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, zipcode

we tied up with a "Delhivery" shipping service.

They gave a list of PIN/ZIP codes for that location only they will ship the products.

what we want is ,In frontend customer have to to enter a "PIN/ZIP" code in "Text field" to find whether the "shipping team"

will deliver the products or not.

So that customer can buy the products only if pin/zip code give "positive message".

we have all pin/zip codes that "shipping team " will deliver [some 1000 pin/zip codes]

how to achieve this in product list page.

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best and easy solution for your requirement is using the table rate. You just need to upload your csv file containing the list of zip codes. and its done.

There is already a field for zip/postcode text field while checkout process in magento. So you need to do nothing.

Have a look on how to enable table rate shipping method in magento.

Hope this will help.

Comment: hi,

thanks a lot for reply, where i have to upload the zip file in magento admin panel....

Comment: After enabling the table rate save it.Now, change your store view from "default" to "Your store" then you can see the place to upload the csv.For detail info visit http://www.sitepoint.com/set-up-table-rate-shipping-in-magento/. If this answer helps you donot forget to accept and vote up. Cheers

Comment: please see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114390/identify-cash-on-delivery-is-availble-or-not-using-zip-postal-code-check-on-prod

Comment: Hey i also have the same question but i want to ask if i can add zipcode range in tables rate csv. Like 305001 - 305050

Comment: Hey @HemantSankhla the default table rate don't provide the postcode range, instead you can use the extension "Matrix rate" which will provide the same with what you require.

Comment: Hey @aton1004 thanks for clarification. Can you suggest some of free extension for the same task.

Comment: @HemantSankhla I think the matrix rate extension is free one. Is your store in magento 1.x or Magento 2? It's definitely free from magento 1. not sure for magento2 though.

Comment: https://webshopapps.com/us/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html for magento 1 and  https://webshopapps.com/us/magento-2-extensions/wsa-standalone/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html/ for M2

Comment: Thanks man. It is free and looks like popular though. Made my day. Thanks again for quick reply.