# identify cash on delivery is availble or not using zip/postal code check on product view page in magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a textfield on "Product- view - page"

so that by entering zip/postal code, customer can check whether "cash on delivery " option is available in their address or not.

I have some 500 zip/pin codes that support cash on delivery.

Comment: You question is not clear and also there is no image you attached. Have you created the "cash on delivery" a shipping method? Do you need that as shipping method? Explain a bit more, so that other can help.

Comment: thanks for reply. in magento by default there is a Cash on delivery payment method is there.

what i need is demo example : http://prntscr.com/6i6rwp

Comment: Update the question with the image if you have uploaded it somewhere. No distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) that includes begging for help and pre-announcements of thanks.  It is not impolite to leave that out but it is wasting readers time when you put it in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you requirement is fulfilled using the **get a quote** block in your product-detail page.

Here is what you need to do:

1. Create a tablerate shipping method named **Cash On Delivery** and upload your csv with price.
2. Use the **Get a Quote** block that is in cart page in default, and place it in product detail page. This can be done from layout i guess.

Now after you get the **Get a Quote** in your product detail page.Show only zip code field and hide other field.

This could solve your problem,if i got it right.

Hope this will help.